# Maximum Likelihood Methods

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Given $\hat{\theta}=\frac{-n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nlog(X_i)}$ is the mle of $\theta$ for a $\beta(\theta,1)$ distribution and $W=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^nlog(X_i)$ has a $\Gamma\left(n,\frac{1}{\theta}\right)$ distribution.  Answer the following:

**i)** Show that $2\theta W$ has a $\chi^2_{(2n)}$ distribution.

**ii)** Using **i)**, find $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that,

$$
Pr\left(c_1<\frac{2\theta n}{\hat{\theta}}<c_2\right)=1-\alpha
$$

for $0<\alpha<1$.  Then, obtain a $(1-\alpha)100\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$.

**iii)** For $\alpha=0.05$ and $n=10$ compare the length of this interval with the length of the interval given by;
$\hat{\theta} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\sqrt{n}}$.

I'm not having trouble with **i)** anymore, but I'm hoping to get some guidance for **ii)** and **iii)**.  For **ii)**, since $\frac{2\theta n}{\hat{\theta}}=2\theta W$ are $c_1$ and $c_2$ equal to $\chi^2_{(2n),\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ and $\chi^2_{(2n),1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ respectively? And then is the $(1-\alpha)100\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ given by;

$$
Pr\left(\frac{\chi^2_{(2n),\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{2W}<\theta<\frac{\chi^2_{(2n),1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{2W}\right),
$$

even though we're dividing by the random variable $W$?  And **iii)** is still confusing to me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And your thoughts on the exercise? Any work to show?

Comment: For **i)**, I've gotten that $2\theta W$ has the same distribution as $2n$, but not sure how that helps me illustrate a $\chi^2_{2n}$ distribution.  For **ii)** I have to manipulate the expression in **i)** to get $\frac{2\theta n}{\hat{\theta}}$ but haven't been able to yet.  And **iii)** depends on what I get for **ii)**, so I'm stuck there as well

Comment: Sorry, "$2\theta W$ has the same distribution as $2n$" meaning?

Comment: You are already given that $W$ has a gamma density which makes the job even lesser. From this, can you show that $2\theta W$ also has a gamma density, and do you recognise that a chi-square distribution is also a gamma distribution?